# Calendar formatting in java

Tags: java, calendar, monthcalendar

I am trying to make a calendar and this part of the code is supposed to print the days.
Right now, when the calendar is complete, the line "|" stop at the final date.  
The box next to the 31 should have a line.
This is what I have so far.

```
    System.out.println("+-----------------------------------------+");
    System.out.println("|               " + months[month] + " " + year + "             |");
    System.out.println("+-----------------------------------------+");
    System.out.println("| Sun | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat |");
    System.out.println("+-----------------------------------------+");

    int d = day(month, 1, year);

    // printing the days
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    System.out.print("|     ");
    for (int i = 1; i <= days[month]; i++) {
       System.out.printf("|   %2d", i);

        if (((i + d) % 7 == 0) || (i == days[month])) System.out.println("|" + "\n" + "|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |" + "\n" + "+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+");

    }

}
```

}

```
Expected Output (Bottom part)

+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  26 |  27 |  28 |  29 |  30 |  31 |     |
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+

Actual Output (Bottom part)


+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   26|   27|   28|   29|   30|   31|
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

Didn't test, but changing `System.out.println()` to `System.out.print()` shoudl do the trick. Like so:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= days[month]; i++) {
   System.out.printf("|   %2d", i);

   if (((i + d) % 7 == 0) || (i == days[month])) System.out.print("|" + "\n" + "|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |" + "\n" + "+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+");
}
```

Comment: If I do that, the numbers are outside the box "+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+|   26|   27|   28|   29|   30|   31|"

Answer (score 2):

You’ve got a separate `for` loop for printing the empty cells before the first of the month. That works. What you need is a similar separate `for` loop that prints the empty cells after the last day of the month.

For this to work correctly after your main `for` loop, you first need to take the printing of the bottom horizontal line out of the loop. So the `if` statement inside you loop becomes just `if ((i + d) % 7 == 0)`.

Now after your main `for` loop insert a new `for` loop for printing the appropriate number of empty cells. You need to find the day of week of the last day of the month (or maybe simpler, of the first day of the next month) to determine how many they are.

Finally draw the bottom horizontal line using the same print statement as in the `if` statement. You may wrap this statement into a method so you can use it in both places.

There’s a special case of the last day of the month being a Sunday. In this case your simplified `if` statement will still draw the line, and you should not draw it again at the end. You’ll find a way to manage.

Comment: I tried several for loops, but I am not sure how to calculate the empty cells after the last day of the month. It either prints the cells outside the box or below it.

Comment: Sorry to hear, @Jake. I don’t know what I can say. Stack Overflow isn’t really well suited for remote debugging.

Comment: Edits that remove fluff [are fine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/6296561). Please refrain from further rollbacks.